# Получение разницы во времени формата hhmm

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть две переменные хранящие время. Одна текущее вторая "требуемое".
формат hhmm. Как получить разницу в виде hhmm или как узнать что одно время больше или меньше другого.
  Уточню речь идет о времени, а не о таймерах. т.е 13.40 - 12.20 = 1.20, 23.30 - 1.30 = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вычислить как разницу в датах используя чистый js

```
const currentDate = new Date();
const lastDate = new Date('2019-02-23T00:00:00');
const diffSeconds = (currentDate - lastDate) / 1000; // будет число миллисекунд, переводим в секунды

const diffHours = diffSeconds / 3600; // получим сколько часов
const hours = parseInt(diffHours); // сколько целых часов
const minutes = parseInt((diffHours - hours) * 60); // берем дробную часть и переводим в минуты
const formatedDate = `${hours}ч ${minutes} мин`;
console.log(`Разница во времени ${formatedDate}`)
```

Comment: Я думал натд таким вариантом, только до минут. Но появилась другая проблема. 23.30 и 1.00 следующего дня.

Comment: Есть еще библиотека MomentJS + moment-duration-format
Возможно будет лучше использовать ее если нужно будет
в принципе делать много манипуляций с датами,
накидал небольшой пример:
https://plnkr.co/edit/SzbhEEMRRu7gXQ1hnaM5

Comment: Спасибо! В итоге сам к этому пришел.